# How to force character casing (capitalized) in a ComboBox C#? Is it possible?

Tags: c#

I'm using a ComboBox control (windows forms) with auto complete, and I found out that there is no CharacterCasing Property on it. What I'm trying to accomplish is to echo upper case letters on the ComboBox.

---

comboBox1.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDown;

//comboBox1.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper  ???

Here's how I populate the comboBox:

```
ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
                pl.cmd = new SqlCommand("LOOKUP", pl.ConnOpen());
                pl.cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                pl.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TABLENAME", (object)tableName));
                pl.da = new SqlDataAdapter(pl.cmd);
                dt = new DataTable("dt");
                pl.da.Fill(dt);
                cb.DataSource = dt;
                cb.ValueMember = valueMember;
                cb.DisplayMember = displayMember;
```

Comment: Silverlight? WPF? Forms?

Comment: If you show us how you are populating/binding the ComboBox, you might get a better answer.

Comment: @spender: I'm using a DataTable to populate my ComboBox.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

[WPF ComboBox, force input to UpperCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092343/wpf-combobox-force-input-to-uppercase)

Comment: Even though this is an old answer, I wanted to make note for future readers that the link is for WPF and not for Windows Forms.