# WPF: Combobox with forced uppercase?

Tags: wpf, combobox, uppercase

I'm not sure why, but none of the solutions are working properly for me from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092343/wpf-combobox-force-input-to-uppercase).

I realize that a `TextBox` has a property (`CharacterCasing`) which can be set to `Upper` to change any lowercase typing into uppercase. It works so great because the user is never interrupted while typing, caps lock and shift don't affect it negatively, and other non-alpha characters aren't affected negatively either.

The problem is that there is no option to use this property for a ComboBox. The solutions from that similar posting don't seem to work for me. I'm looking to duplicate the CharacterCasing property but for a ComboBox. I don't mind it being an attached property, in fact, that'd be great. I tried a couple of different events directly on the xaml object, with no success.

Answer (score 15):

The `ComboBox` template uses a `TextBox` when `IsEditable` is true. So you can either replace the template to set `CharacterCasing` on the `TextBox`, or create an attached property that will find the `TextBox` by its name ("PART_EditableTextBox") and set the `CharacterCasing` property on it.

Here's a simple implementation of the attached property solution:

```
public static class ComboBoxBehavior
{

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(ComboBox))]
    public static CharacterCasing GetCharacterCasing(ComboBox comboBox)
    {
        return (CharacterCasing)comboBox.GetValue(CharacterCasingProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCharacterCasing(ComboBox comboBox, CharacterCasing value)
    {
        comboBox.SetValue(CharacterCasingProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CharacterCasing.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CharacterCasingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "CharacterCasing",
            typeof(CharacterCasing),
            typeof(ComboBoxBehavior),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(
                CharacterCasing.Normal,
                OnCharacterCasingChanged));

    private static void OnCharacterCasingChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = o as ComboBox;
        if (comboBox == null)
            return;

        if (comboBox.IsLoaded)
        {
            ApplyCharacterCasing(comboBox);
        }
        else
        {
            // To avoid multiple event subscription
            comboBox.Loaded -= new RoutedEventHandler(comboBox_Loaded);
            comboBox.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(comboBox_Loaded);
        }
    }

    private static void comboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        if (comboBox == null)
            return;

        ApplyCharacterCasing(comboBox);
        comboBox.Loaded -= comboBox_Loaded;
    }

    private static void ApplyCharacterCasing(ComboBox comboBox)
    {
        var textBox = comboBox.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", comboBox) as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            textBox.CharacterCasing = GetCharacterCasing(comboBox);
        }
    }

}
```

And here's how to use it:

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              IsEditable="True"
              local:ComboBoxBehavior.CharacterCasing="Upper">
        ...
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me... is it not usable in a User Control? In particular the line `var textBox = comboBox.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", comboBox) as TextBox;` sets textBox as null, which is why the `CharacterCasing` never gets applied.

Comment: That's weird... I tested it and it worked fine for me. Did you set IsEditable to true ? If it's false, the ComboBox uses a different template, which doesn't contain a TextBox

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't working either. I put a debugging stop on that line and checked the properties of comboBox. IsEditable is set to true.

Comment: Are you using a custom ControlTemplate for your ComboBox? If so, check if it contains an element with the appropriate name (PART_EditableTextBox). It is possible to use ControlTemplates that don't contain such an element, but then of course this implementation will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the good solution... I would add `comboBox.Loaded -= comboBox_Loaded;` just before you add the handler (in your else block). This is just a slight optimization in the case that PropertyChanged is called multiple times before the control is loaded (as far as I know this should be possible and it would result in repeated calls to ApplyCharacterCasing, even tho it would work just fine)